# Adding/substracting a scalar to a constant

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:

$$ Ax = \lambda x $$
$$ Ax - \lambda x = 0 $$

The following dos not makes sense since $\lambda$ is a scalar

$$ x(A - \lambda) = 0 $$

And hence we write

$$ x(A - \lambda I) = 0 $$

I have issues with this,  as in my mind, $\lambda I \neq \lambda$

How does one justify adding the identity term?

Comment: Assuming $A$ and $I$ are matrices, then $Ax$ is not the same thing as $xA$, so your equation should be $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$, with the $x$ on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we always have the distributive laws for matrices of appropriate dimensions:
\begin{align*}
(A \pm B)C &= AC \pm BC \\
A(B \pm C) &= AB \pm AC.
\end{align*}
Since $(\lambda I)x = \lambda x$, we can therefore say
$$(A - \lambda I)x = Ax - (\lambda I)x = Ax - \lambda x.$$
It's fully justified by the distributive laws and the simple fact about $\lambda I$.

On the other hand, $(A - \lambda)x = Ax - \lambda x$ is not justified at all, and as you pointed out, completely meaningless. It only appears to make sense in a purely symbolic manipulation sense, divorced of context. This isn't how we (should) do mathematics! Everything we do should have some meaning behind it.

(Also, beware of changing the order of multiplication. You wrote $x(A - \lambda)$, which even if we correctly changed $\lambda$ to $\lambda I$, this would still render the multiplication meaningless, as the dimensions would no longer line up. Again, please be careful!)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lambda$ is a scalar and $A$ is a matrix, so $A-\lambda$ doesn't actually make sense.

However, the original expression was the completely sensible $Ax-\lambda x$. And if you want to take $x$ "out" of that expression, you have to make sure that what you leave behind is compatible with one another. Thus we rewrite $\lambda x$ to $\lambda I x$ (hopefully you can agree that *these* two are indeed equal, even though $\lambda$ and $\lambda I$ aren't). Now we get
$$
Ax - \lambda x = Ax - \lambda Ix = (A-\lambda I)x
$$
PS. It is, however, rather common to *write* $\lambda$ when we mean $\lambda I$ in an expression like this. So $(A-\lambda)x$ is not an uncommon expression. Just be aware that it's a shorthand, and you'll be fine. And in the context of linear transformations rather than matrices, $A-\lambda$ is actually sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I’m sure you agree that $\lambda 1=\lambda$. Writing $\lambda I$, even though it feels different, is the exact same thing since $I$ is the $1$ element in the ring of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

note that for $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $A,B\in \Bbb R$ we have $$I_nx=x$$and $$(A+B)x=Ax+Bx$$